# UIViewController sub-subclass not recognized in Xcode 6.0 Beta when using Swift

Tags: uiviewcontroller, subclass, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to convert a simple app from Objective C to Swift. It's based on one BaseViewController, which is then subclassed.

I've created a project with just these two classes - BaseViewController and ChildViewController.

ChildViewController has a xib file, and when I right click on File Properties, I would expect to see the IBOutlets of BaseViewController - but I don't and the view property is also no longer there.

**BaseViewController**

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var customButton: UIBarButtonItem
    @IBOutlet var _activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func customButtonAction() {    
    }
}
```

**ChildViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ChildViewController: BaseViewController {

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func customButtonAction() {
    }
}
```

I gather that swift classes init differently to objective-c and if the above no longer works in swift, is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: _"If the above works"_ then you don't have a question.  Do you want somebody to test the code for you?

Comment: Thanks for responding - I may have phrased that wrong - the code compiles, but I cannot see any of the base controller's IBOutlets in the child controller

Comment: You ought to change the title too - the current one is _very_ general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right. This seems to be a bug in the current version of Xcode 6.0 (6A215l).

Inheritance is straightforward and the missing `IBOutlets` have nothing to do with `init`. The interface builder component simply doesn't seem to recognize that `ChildViewController` is a `UIViewController` when using Swift. I'm sure it will be fixed in a later Xcode build.

**Edit:** This has been fixed in Xcode 6 Beta 3. From the release notes:

> You can now declare an outlet’s type to be a class that is implemented
>   in Swift and connect it to an object in an Interface Builder document.
>   You can also declare outlets in a Swift class and connect them to an
>   instance of one of its subclasses in an Interface Builder document.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll file a bug report with Apple.